# Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead

Tags: qt, qml

There is a QML `ToolBar`. I can build/run the app with Qt **5.9** without any error. But when building/running the app with Qt **5.11**, I received this error:

> QML EnableButton: Detected **anchors** on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use **Layout.alignment** instead.

The above error occurs at the `ToolbarButton` declarations at in tool-bar code:

```
ToolBar {
    id: mainToolBar
    anchors.fill: parent
    style: ToolBarStyle {
        padding.top: 0
        padding.bottom: 0
        padding.right: 0
        padding.left: 0
        background: Rectangle {
            implicitHeight: newButton.height
            color: editorContent.itemBackgroundColor
        }
    }

    RowLayout {
        spacing: 0

        ToolbarButton {
            id: newButton
            enabledIconSource: "images/new.png"
            tooltip: qsTr("New") + editorScene.emptyString
            onEnabledButtonClicked: editorContent.fileNew()
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        }
        ToolbarButton {
            enabledIconSource: "images/load.png"
            tooltip: qsTr("Load (Ctrl + O)") + editorScene.emptyString
            onEnabledButtonClicked: editorContent.fileLoad()
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
        }
        // ...
        // ...
```

---

I don't have any `anchors` in the `ToolbarButton` code whatsoever, instead, I'm actually using `Layout.alignment` in `ToolbarButton` code. I don't understand why such an error is thrown.

---

The whole project I'm trying to build with Qt 5.11 is available here:

https://github.com/qt-labs/qt3d-editor

To resolve the error, I replaced `anchors` with `Layout.alignment`, but it didn't help.

Comment: remove `anchors.fill: parent` in Toolbar

Comment: @eyllanesc Thanks. I removed `anchors.fill: parent`, but I'm receiving the same errors again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `anchors` is in the [ToolbarButton](https://github.com/qt-labs/qt3d-editor/blob/master/editorlib/qml/ToolbarButton.qml) implementation. It's usually not a good idea to reference somewhere outside a component implementation, especially do any anchoring. It should be done by layout (e.g. Toolbar). Your ToolbarButton doesn't support vertical toolbars.

Comment: `anchors.verticalCenter` could be set to `undefined` to cancel the set value.

Comment: of course, but you (or your components user) have to do it each time manually

Comment: In my case, `Rectangle` is anchored to fill parent (a `StackLayout`)，why is there such an error?

Comment: Crawl.W,  positioning within `StackLayout` should be done by `Layout.fillWidth` and `Layout.fillHeight`.